# Meteor.js(react) shows a white page after adding webpack. (No rendered)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, meteor

I added webpack to my meteor.js project with a hard time. and successfully runing now. but I'm facing now another issue.

Compilation screen

[image: 1]

Compiled successfully but I can't see anything on the browser(http://localhost:3000).

Project Structure

[image: 2]

Thanks in advance.